# Ideas Needed: AngularJS: Select Dropdown with several Option Tags

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select tag with several options underneath:

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    <label class="left-padding">
      <font color="white">Custom: </font>
        <select name="options" ng-model="PODOptions">
            <option value="" select> </option>
            <option value="Extended View">Show Extended View</option>
            <option value="">Hide Extended View</option>
            <option value="Filter">Show Filter</option>
            <option value="">Hide Filter</option>
        </select>
    </label>
  </form>
```

and I would like to show and hide different parts of my page when the user selects an option.
I have binded the select option result to PODOptions. "Filter" refers to my vertical navbar:

```
        <div class="sidebar-nav vertical-nav">
         ...
        </div>
```

which I would like to hide when the user selects Hide Filter and show when the user selects show filter and my "Extended View" refers to a different section of another div on the page that I would like to show and hide upon selection of an option.

At the moment, I have been using ng-switch to control what is rendered on the page, however I run into problems when the user selects "Show Filter" and then "Show Extended View" since both the filter and the extended views should be shown, but as soon as PODOptions gets binded to a new variable, the Filter option goes away.

There must be a better way to do this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: not 100% clear what issue is , but seems like 3 radios ( or toggle buttons)  would work better. One for clear filters, one for showing "Filter" and third for show both  types

Comment: I would like to control both the "extended view" and "filter" with 1 drop down (select tag) unless there is a better way to arrange it?

Comment: still not 100% clear what the main issue is. A simple demo might help

Comment: I am trying to hide and show 2 different views with the selection of a dropdown menu. When the user clicks "Show Extended View" and then "Show Filter", I want both the views to be rendered. However, currently since the selection tag is binded to PODOptions, if I select both of them, the value of "Extended View" will be overwritten by "Filter" and so only Filters view will show. I am wondering if there is a way around this or if there is a better setup I could take?

Comment: please don't paste code that long into comment blocks. It can't be read there. Without a controller and a little bit of data, the html by itself isn't a lot of use anyway. For demos there are several resources like [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) or jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes sorry. That was a mistake.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select name="options" ng-model="PODOptions" ng-change="PODOptionsHandler()">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="extendedView">Extended View</option>
    <option value="hideExtendedView">Hide Extended View</option>
    <option value="showFilter">Show Filter</option>
    <option value="hideFilter">Hide Filter</option>
</select>

<div class="sidebar-nav vertical-nav" ng-show="showFilter">

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.PODOptionsHandler = function(){

    switch ($scope.PODOptions) {

        case 'showFilter':
            $scope.showFilter = true;
            break;
        case 'hideFilter':
            $scope.showFilter = false;
            break;
        case 'extendedView':
            $scope.extendedView = true;
            break;
        case 'hideExtendedView':
            $scope.extendedView = false;
            break;
    }

    $scope.PODOptions = '';

};
```